# Sitecore WFFM and CRM - missing field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm using Web Forms For Marketers alongside CRM as my save action however I'm using the following connection string:

```
<add name="CRMConnString"  
connectionString="CRM:url="http://site/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmService.asmx;
user id=username;password=pass;" />
```

This connects to the CRM successfully, however some of fields aren't available to map within WFFM lastname being one of them. Looking at the XML output lastname is successfully listed under contact.

I've tried to connect to 2011 organizations.svc but have been unable to connect to this successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am unsure where you are trying to map, but if you are talking about in the WFFM editor, I think you might need to look at the profile. As fare as I remember the profile properties are the one listed, and you might need to create a special profile for your CRM

Comment: We are trying to use Web forms for Marketers with CRM 2011 using the Sitecore plugins and the save actions on WFFM.  I've added the CRM string into my connections config.  However when using the CrmServic.asmx some fields aren't being returned within CRM Contact save actions, last name being one of them.

Comment: Also we have tried changing the config to point to Organization.svc but when trying to add CRM Contact as a save action within WFFM we get an error message that the configuration doesn't support it

Comment: We have just discovered that if the field's requirement level is set to business required then it doesn't appear within WFFM.  Is there a way around this within Sitecore?